# Coldfusion cfhttp with HTTPS not working although all certificates installed

Tags: https, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I know this question has been asked a lot already, but although I've been searching for days now I didn't find a suitable answer.

We are running Coldfusion 9 Standard with JDK 1.7. I'm trying to perform a request with cfhttp, following code:

```
 <cfhttp url="Https://subdomain.example.com" method="get"  result="result" username="#myUsername#" password="#myPassword#" />
```

I get the following when dumping out the result:

[[image: 1]]

I already imported all certificates in the certificate chain to the right keystore. The CA is Let's Encrypt. Funny thing is, we have another site from which we are asking a webservice, also with certificate from Let's Encrypt and it is working. Accessed from the same Coldfusion server.

I also tried following code in onApplicationStart in Application.cfc, but didn't work:

```
<cfif NOT isDefined("Application.sslfix")>
    <cfset objSecurity = createObject("java", "java.security.Security") />
    <cfset objSecurity.removeProvider("JsafeJCE") />
    <cfset Application.sslfix = true />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Already said that in the Question. Coldfusion 9, jdk 1.7

Comment: Can you try to add `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` to the JVM Arguments in your CFAdmin.

Comment: Added and restarted server. Unfortunately didn't help :(

Comment: `CF9`, has this issue when it comes to `TLS 1.1+` but there is no straight forward fix for this that I know of. You can try this plugin. But it is not free. https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/02/tls-1-2-for-coldfusion-9-and-older/

Comment: Removed the whole sslfix block in Application.cfc, restarted app, but still doesn't work.

Comment: I really would like to upgrade Coldfusion but sadly that's not my descision and not an option.

Comment: I found the answer but can't write it cause of reputation. Maybe someone else would do me the favour.

Comment: I simply had to add 'port="443"' to the cfhttp tag, so we have now <cfhttp port="443" url="Https://subdomain.example.com" method="get"  result="result" username="#myUsername#" password="#myPassword#" />

And it works just fine. I'm crying because I didn't try that earlier. Strange thing is that with the other request I don't have to specify the port and it works fine.

Comment: Did you try with out the java config setting? Great thing that it is fixed now!!!!!

Comment: @coldfusiondrivesmecrazy - It would help others to know if that is with or without the `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` setting (not all sites have switched to TLS1.2 yet). Also, post your exact JVM and CF version (use `<cfdump var="#server#">`) FWIW, you should still be able to post an answer. Though S.O. might make you wait a little.

Comment: FAQ's say [answering only requires 1 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts). If it's still not working in while, and there's no message explaining why you can't post, open a question on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply had to add `port="443"` to the `cfhttp` tag, which made the following code works just fine:

```
<cfhttp port="443" url="Https://subdomain.example.com" 
   method="get" 
   result="result" 
   username="#myUsername#" 
   password="#myPassword#" />
```

I'm crying because I didn't try that earlier. Strange thing is that with the other request I don't have to specify the port and it works fine.

I also removed the setting below from the JVM Settings. It didn't have any effect on my problem.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Life saver. Works great with the port attribute. However, shouldn't it be result="Response"? result="result" crashes my CF.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this is related to JRE. Your coldfusion server working with TLS 1.0 i think. So, you need to update the coldfusion server JRE.

For adding this, follow below steps,

1. Upgrade to Java 8.
2. Login to ColdFusion Administrator > Java JVM
3. Change the path of the JVM to the new installed path (defaults to: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102 in windows. )
4. Restart ColdFusion Server - Service.
5. Re-Test.. it should work now..